# Internal server error: Preprocessor dependency "sass" not found. Did you install it?

Tags: npm, vite

I created a new VUE 3 and typescript application using vite.  I later installed primevue and primeflex.  When I run npm run dev, I get the error seen below:

[image]

How do I fix this?  My [repo](https://github.com/isogunro/my-app), if that will shed light.

Answer (score 57):

Install the sass package.

```
npm install --save-dev sass
```

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: What is important here is that it is a `dev` dependancy, not a production one.

Answer (score 15):

Your repository does not show `sass` as a dev dependancy.

As mentioned by [@justsomexanda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74212757/1310132), you should install the `sass` package to your dev dependency with your package manager of choice:

```
yarn add -D sass

# or:
npm add --save-dev sass
```

Then, **stop** and **restart** your dev server to make sure changes are taken into account:

```
yarn dev

# or:
npm run dev
```

Please note that HMR will not work directly after installing the `sass` package without restarting the dev server, leading to the error message you mentioned: *"Preprocessor dependency "sass" not found. Did you install it?"*.

For further details, [here is the Vite documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#css-pre-processors) about CSS preprocessors.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Vite JS and installing Sass for the project.

Follow the below commands to make it work:

1. `npm add --save-dev node-sass` OR `yarn add --save-dev node-sass`
2. `npm add --save-dev sass` OR `yarn add --save-dev sass`

Now run development and check.

Share errors in the comments if you're still getting any errors.

Answer (score 1):

1. delete node_modules directory
2. delete package-lock.json
3. run `npm i`